# How to properly set buffer and bufsize with getpwuid_r()?

Tags: c, linux, struct, operating-system, filesystems

### Background Info

I am trying to get the string of a user's username, with the only info provided about that user being their `uid` number. I have the `uid` as a result of a preceding call to `fstat` (and the `uid` is stored in a `struct stat`).

I need to get the username in a thread-safe manner, and so I am trying to use `getpwuid_r()`. According to the `getpwuid (3)` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3p.html):

```
int getpwuid_r(uid_t uid, struct passwd *pwd, char *buffer,
       size_t bufsize, struct passwd **result);
```

> The `getpwuid_r()` function shall update the `passwd` structure pointed
>          to by `pwd` and store a pointer to that structure at the location
>          pointed to by result.  The structure shall contain an entry from 
>          the user database with a matching `uid`.  Storage referenced by the
>          structure is allocated from the memory provided with the buffer
>          parameter, which is `bufsize` bytes in size. A call to
>          `sysconf(_SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX)` returns either −1 without changing
>          `errno` or an initial value suggested for the size of this buffer.  A
>          null pointer shall be returned at the location pointed to by result
>          on error or if the requested entry is not found.
>
> If successful, the `getpwuid_r()` function shall return zero;
>          otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error.

---

### Problem Statement

Upon reading the man page example below, I am confused as to why they need to iterate, while increasing the size of the buffer, until the buffer can hold its information.

I am under the presumption that the buffer holds the `struct passwd pwd` - considering this, why can't we just set `buffer = (void *) malloc(getsize(struct passwd))` and `bufsize = sizeof(struct passwd)`?

```
long int initlen = sysconf(_SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX);
size_t len;
if (initlen == −1)
    /* Default initial length. */
    len = 1024;
else
    len = (size_t) initlen;
struct passwd result;
struct passwd *resultp;
char *buffer = malloc(len);
if (buffer == NULL)
    ...handle error...
int e;
while ((e = getpwuid_r(42, &result, buffer, len, &resultp)) == ERANGE)
{
    size_t newlen = 2 * len;
    if (newlen < len)
        ...handle error...
    len = newlen;
    char *newbuffer = realloc(buffer, len);
    if (newbuffer == NULL)
        ...handle error...
    buffer = newbuffer;
}
if (e != 0)
    ...handle error...
free (buffer);
```

Is there something I'm not understanding about how this function sets the data within `pwd`? Perhaps I don't fully understand how the `struct passwd` we are setting is related to the buffer space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `passwd` struct is defined by the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/pwd.h.html) to contain at least these members:

```
char    *pw_name   // User's login name. 
uid_t    pw_uid    // Numerical user ID. 
gid_t    pw_gid    // Numerical group ID. 
char    *pw_dir    // Initial working directory. 
char    *pw_shell  // Program to use as shell.
```

Note the three `char *` members; they point to storage that lies elsewhere, outside of the struct.
Many implementations will have two more `char *` members: `pw_passwd` and `pw_gecos`.

The difference between `getpwuid` and `getpwuid_r` is that the former may use a static buffer to store the name, passwd, dir, gecos, and shell strings<sup>1</sup> - as well as the `passwd` struct itself - while the latter, since it's reentrant, requires the user to supply one buffer to hold `struct passwd` and another buffer to hold the character strings.

In practice, the two functions share a lot of [common code](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/passwd/getgr_a.c).

> I am confused as to why they need to iterate, while increasing the size of the buffer, until the buffer can hold its information.

If the call to `sysconf(_SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX)` fails, you just have to guess how big the buffer for the character strings should be, and keep increasing its size until it's big enough.

<sup>1</sup> In [V7](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/libc/stdio/getpwent.c), when all the info was in `/etc/passwd`, this static buffer was just a copy of the appropriate line of /etc/passwd with a NUL inserted at the end of each of the five string fields.